# CSRF Mitigation With Cookie Same-Site

Tags: csrf

wanted to get some advise in our OAuth process of getting token from 3rd party. Any comment would be appreciated!

1. User click a short link and rediredirected to original link https://webssite.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENTID&scope=SCOPE&callback=CALLBACK_URL
2. User facing 3rd party login form
3. After user login successfully, 3rd party redirecting user to our
   server following the URL we set in the URL
4. Our server receives the request and set encrypted cookie with
   Same-Site value Strict and redirect to our authorized page

Is the cookie with same-site value strict is enough to prevent CSRF in this case? (edited)

Comment: You’d probably want to use Lax because Strict would break the flow, afaict. Strict instructs user-agents not to send SameSite Strict cookies at all, unless it’s same-same.